# How to programmatically answer a call

Tags: android, phone-call

I know [this has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610587/how-to-programmatically-answer-a-call), but at this time the answer of the post is not true. Vringo and other apps does answer the phone by pressing a button on their app, so there must be a way to do it.

Anyone has a suggestion?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Check out this source:

http://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer/AutoAnswerIntentService.java

They send a Bluetooth "keydown" event to answer the call!

Comment: Please fix this link or provide other link. i relay need this functionality..Thanks

Comment: which of the functions work for answering the call? or maybe both? if so, which is better? do they work for all android versions? also, since the code is quite short, maybe you should post it here...

Answer (score 3):

This solution is 'funny', 
it 'almost' works on my HUAWEI Y300 (4.1.1) but on my LG E410 Swift L1 (4.1.2) not.

On HUAWEI it works with KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, when on LG there is no reaction for ACTION_UP event.
From other side, on HUAWEI the ACTION_DOWN event does not answer a call, but on LG it rejects it.

So different models of a devices have different reactions.

Someone has some updates in this issue ? Is there an another working solution, which behaves in same way for all mobile phones, and does not require from a device to be rooted ?