# How to play audio file to call?

Tags: android

How do I play audio file to a call  for android? 
I want to make some kind of machine answering program. is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be able to intercept incoming calls.

ETA: er, apparently that isn't true? See:

[How to programmatically answer a call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765980/android-how-to-programmatically-answer-a-call)