# Is there a way to automatically answer incoming cell calls?

Tags: android

Is there a way to automatically answer an incoming cell call from an android application? I know it can be detected etc. but can it be programmatically answered?

Comment: Probably not, otherwise an app could answer and hang up on everyone that calls you and you'd never know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - How to programmatically answer a call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765980/android-how-to-programmatically-answer-a-call)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto answer the incoming call programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740223/auto-answer-the-incoming-call-programatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this questions:

- [Android - How to programmatically answer a call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765980/android-how-to-programmatically-answer-a-call)
- [How to programmatically answer a call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610587/how-to-programmatically-answer-a-call)