# How to Answer incoming call through adb shell or keyevent

Tags: android, android-intent, androidviewclient

I am trying to answer an incoming call using Intent as below :

```
device.shell("am start -n com.android.phone/.InCallScreen -a android.intent.action.ANSWER")
```

can anyone please tell where am i going wrong ... please help .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481524/how-to-programatically-answer-end-a-call-in-android-4-1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805796/how-to-programmatically-answer-a-call-in-android-4-0-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

device.press("KEYCODE_CALL","DOWN")

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Answer incoming call in Android](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html)

Check out the [source Code](https://code.google.com/p/auto-answer/source/browse/trunk/src/com/everysoft/autoanswer/AutoAnswerIntentService.java)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its working fine for me.

```
public static void answerCall(Context context) {

     Intent buttonDown = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);       
     buttonDown.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
     context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonDown, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");             

    // froyo and beyond trigger on buttonUp instead of buttonDown
    Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT,
      new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");  
}
```